# How to convert and or upload project with hierarchical structure to Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, project

My project

[image]

My colab

[image]

For example, with many Python source code files in per folder/directory

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import viet_text_tools as vtts
from preprocessing import *

class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df, tag_names, tokenizer, ):
        self.df = df
        self.df["sent"] = self.df["sent"].apply(vtts.normalize_diacritics)
        self.tag_names = tag_names
        self.sents, self.annos = [words.split() for words in list(df["sent"].values)], [tags.split() for tags in
                                                                                        list(df["anno"].values)]
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = 64
        self.criterion_ignored_la = -100
        self.specials = {
            "pad_token_id": self.tokenizer.pad_token_id,
            "cls_token_id": self.tokenizer.cls_token_id,
            "sep_token_id": self.tokenizer.sep_token_id,
            "pad_token_la": self.criterion_ignored_la,
            "cls_token_la": self.criterion_ignored_la,
            "sep_token_la": self.criterion_ignored_la,
        }

    def show_sent(self, idx):
        sent, anno = self.sents[idx], self.annos[idx]
        print("{:>40}: {}".format("word", "tag"))
        for i in range(len(sent)):
            print("{:>40}: {}".format(sent[i], anno[i]))

    def __len__(self):
        dataset_len = len(self.df)
        return dataset_len

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sent, anno = self.sents[idx], self.annos[idx]
        sent, anno = pad_and_add_special_tokens(self, *tokenize(self, sent, anno).values()).values()
        sent, anno = np.array(sent), np.array(anno)
        return sent, anno
```

How to convert and or upload project with hierarchical structure to Google Colab?

Comment: How bout uploading your project to github and then cloning the repo on Colab?

Comment: This is my project https://github.com/donhuvy/vy_thesis , as you seen, it is not `*.ipynb` files.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here that requires the upload to Colab?

Comment: I need run project in Google colab where has GPU for machine learning task (PyTorch)

Comment: `.py` files can also be edited and executed on colab.

Comment: You seem to assume that colab can only run python notebooks, but that is not true.